# Issue at like operation for numbers in oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

This is a project on java with `openjpa ORM`. I have an issue with like selection for type `NUMBER(10,2)` in Oracle database.

The type of number in `JPA is BigDecimal` and numbers could be like integer and not integer, for example:

```
123456
or 123456,01; 123456,15
```

At presentation layer user has global filter, but not only for this column, where he can choose column and operator (like, equal or between) and define value.

For examaple: column1 like '%56%'

Also numbers at presentation layer has presision 2, so:

```
123456,00 ->'123456,00'
123456,01 -> '123456,01'
```

When Oracle database executes like opearaion, nuber is converted ot String type:

```
123456,00 -> '123456'
and 123456,01 -> '123456,01'
```

So the result of operation column1 `like '%,0%'` is only

`123456,01` but not both.

I also tried call native SQL function like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341668/create-custom-jpa-query-function) but we use OpenJPA 1.2.3 with JPA 1.0 implementation.

Please help me find workaround at my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps you but on Oracle side you should use:

```
select * 
from your_table
where to_char(your_column,'99999999.99') like '%.0%';
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this solution, but it does not help me, because all global filter is implemented on jpql.

Comment: JPA 1.0 allows custom SQL to be used for queres, so you can use this instead of straight JPQL. Just use createNativeQuery(sqlString, Entity.class) instead to create it.  There maybe better OpenJPA specific options, but this might allow you to continue until you can find one